# Representation of Triangle vertices permutations group in $\Bbb{R}^2$

Tags: representation-theory

Let $S_3$ be the symmetry group of vertices permutations of equilateral triangle in $\Bbb{R}^2$ with origin in $0$.

1. Show that the group operation of $S_3$ could be extended to a linear map $\rho (\sigma), \sigma\in S_3$ over the plane.
2. Show that $\rho : S_3 \to GL(\Bbb{R}^2)$ is a group representation.

Our course definition of a representation of a (finite group) is a pair $(V,\rho)$ where $V$ is a vector space over a field $\Bbb{F}$ and $\rho: \Bbb{G}\to GL(V)$ is a homomorphism between a group $G$ and a space of invertible linear transformations.

This is a Group Representation Theory question, and I am a little confused about the different elements in $S_3$. How can I define element of $S_3$ so that they can be mapped into reflection and rotation matrices in $GL(\Bbb{R}^2)$? I could use some help. I am really not sure what I am doing here. Do the matrices of reflections and rotations have anything to do with it?

So I guess my group is a group of permutations, which I hope can be represented as a set of $2\times 3$ matrices where the first row is $(A B C)$ for each vertex and the second is any of the 6 rearrangements of "ABC".

So my $\rho$ takes a such permutation and maps it to a rotation matrix or a reflection rotation matrix in $\Bbb{R}^2$, but other than writing permutation and saying that $
    \begin{pmatrix}
    A & B & C \\
    C & A & B \\
    \end{pmatrix} 
$ fits
\begin{pmatrix}
{\cos({2\pi\over 3})} & {-\sin({2\pi\over 3})}  \\
{\cos({2\pi\over 3})} &  {\cos({2\pi\over 3})}  \\
\end{pmatrix}

is there anything more specific I am required to?

Comment: I don't believe that fact 1 is true. If an element of the symmetric group takes the origin to a non-origin element, it cannot possible extend to a linear map.

Comment: Maybe it meant to take the general functions of rotation and reflections and map it to the $2\times 2 $ matrix that applies that function?

Comment: Yeah, that might be the case.

Comment: Because it's origin is zero no shifts are necessary, and so the extension only uses rotations around the origin

Comment: I think the assumption that origin of triangle is 0 should be rephrased. it should be assumed that the centroid of the triangle is 0. This means that $v_1+v_2+v_3=0$. This way every permutation of the 3 vertices in the plane can be extended to a linear transformation.

Answer (score 1):

In 1 you need to show that for every permutation $\sigma\in S_3$, there is a linear map $\rho(\sigma): \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$ (i.e. a matrix) such that applying $\rho(\sigma)$ to the vertices of the equilateral triangle gives the same result as applying the permutation $\sigma$ to the vertices. This is basically what you have done for a specific permutation at the end of your question.

For 2 you need to show that $\rho$ actually is a representation of $S_3$. I.e. that
$
\rho(\sigma\circ\tau) = \rho(\sigma)\rho(\tau).
$